# High-dimensionality of multi-electron wavefunctions

Tags: wavefunction, quantum-entanglement, superconductivity, many-body

My understanding is that the main difficulties in understanding superconductivity and topological insulators is related to the fact that free electrons are highly entangled and models that simplify the electrons as single charge carriers fail to capture all aspects of the relevant phenomena

To complicate things, highly entangled multi-electron systems are hard to simulate in computers because the computational resources grow exponentially with the numbers of entangled quanta, so anything more a handful of them is beyond current and foreseeable technological capabilities

But we have some insights of high dimensional systems. We know that as dimension grows, the ratio between surfaces and volumes shrink dramatically. A fermionic wavefunction has a natural boundary hypersurface where the amplitude is zero, which is the boundary imposed by the exclusion principle.

The insight I want to validate here is this: At high dimensions, we would expect most of the probability to be concentrated around the boundaries. What can we infer from this? **Can we understand things like Cooper pairs as perturbations moving along the hypersurface of amplitude zero?**

Comment: "A fermionic wavefunction has a natural boundary hypersurface where the amplitude is zero, which is the boundary imposed by the exclusion principle." Can you expand on what you mean here?

Comment: so, anti-symmetry means that wavefunctions that have closely stacked quanta in configuration space will have a point in the line of continuous permutation of nearby quanta that must be zero